# Como incluir dados de uma consulta com várias linhas em um memo usando Delphi?

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Boa tarde.

Trabalho em um sistema legado e preciso colocar as informações de uma query em um único objeto memo.

Código segue.

```
MyQuery.Close;

with MyQuery.SQL do
begin
     clear;
     add(' select TOP 8 nuentrada, dstpleitu, vlleitura, dshint, dtleitura, hhleitura ');
     add(' from ssdentsinaisvitais inner join ssttplei on ssdentsinaisvitais.cdleitura = ssttplei.cdleitura ');
     add(' where nuentrada = ' + lblnuentrada.Caption);
     add(' order by dtleitura desc, hhleitura desc ');
 end;

 MyQuery.Open;

 while MyQuery.Eof do
 begin
      mmdsexamefisico.Text := mmdsexamefisico.Text + MyQuery.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('dstpleitu').AsString + ': ';
      mmdsexamefisico.Text := mmdsexamefisico.Text + MyQuery.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('vlleitura').AsString + #13#10;
 end;
```

Ocorre um erro de síntaxe próximo à palavra order.

Conseguem detectar o erro?

---

A `query` formada é a seguinte:

```
SELECT TOP 8 nuentrada,
             dstpleitu,
             vlleitura,
             dshint,
             dtleitura,
             hhleitura
  FROM ssdentsinaisvitais
       INNER JOIN ssttplei ON ssdentsinaisvitais.cdleitura = ssttplei.cdleitura 
 WHERE nuentrada = 350000701778
 ORDER BY dtleitura DESC,
       hhleitura DESC
```

Comment: Antes do `Open` dê um `ShowMessage(MyQuery.SQL.Text);` e informe qual a `query` que foi formada;

Comment: Olá! select TOP 8 nuentrada, dstpleitu, vlleitura, dshint, dtleitura, hhleitura 
from ssdentsinaisvitais inner join ssttplei on ssdentsinaisvitais.cdleitura = ssttplei.cdleitura 
where nuentrada = 350000701778
order by dtleitura desc, hhleitura desc

Comment: Tá explicado então, o tamanho máximo do inteiro no SQL Server é 2147483647

Comment: Tem que ver então se você não quer passar como string, se quiser vc passa assim: `add(' where nuentrada = ''' + lblnuentrada.Caption + '''');`

Comment: Cola o erro pra gente aí

Comment: Você tentou passar outro valor em vez de 350000701778? por exemplo 100.

Comment: 1) Qual é o tipo de dados da coluna "nuentrada"? 2) Você está usando TFDQuery, TADOQuery ..etc?

Comment: Olá, pessoal! Estou usando o objeto TQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde a todos.

O problema foi resolvido colocando um MyQuery.next no fim do while, conforme abaixo.

```
MyQuery.Close;

with MyQuery.SQL do
begin
     clear;
     add(' select TOP 8 nuentrada, dstpleitu, vlleitura, dshint, dtleitura, hhleitura ');
     add(' from ssdentsinaisvitais inner join ssttplei on ssdentsinaisvitais.cdleitura = ssttplei.cdleitura ');
     add(' where nuentrada = ' + lblnuentrada.Caption);
     add(' order by dtleitura desc, hhleitura desc ');
 end;

 MyQuery.Open;

 while MyQuery.Eof do
 begin
      mmdsexamefisico.Text := mmdsexamefisico.Text + MyQuery.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('dstpleitu').AsString + ': ';
      mmdsexamefisico.Text := mmdsexamefisico.Text + MyQuery.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('vlleitura').AsString + #13#10;
      MyQuery.next;
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando o tipo de dados `BIGINT` em vez do tipo de dados `INT`, pois o valor máximo de `INT` é `2.147.483.647`, você pode consultar os [documentos on-line](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)<sub>[1]</sub> aqui para ver. Considere também usar parâmetros para evitar esses erros e [injeção de SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) <sub>[2]</sub>.

♦ Se você estiver usando `TFDQuery`:

```
Const
  Num: Largeint = 350000701778;
Var
  FDQuery: TFDQuery;
begin
  FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(Nil);
  try
    with FDQuery do
      begin
        Connection:= FDConnection1;
        SQL.Text:= 'SELECT ... WHERE Table.nuentrada = :Param';
        Params.CreateParam(ftLargeint, 'Param', ptInput);
        ParamByName('Param').AsLargeInt:= Num;
        Open();
        DataSource.DataSet:= FDQuery;
      end;
  finally
    //FD.Free;
  end;
end;
```

♦ Se você estiver usando `TADOQuery`:

```
Const
  Num: Largeint = 350000701778;
Var
  ADOQuery: TADOQuery;
begin
  ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(Nil);
  try
    with ADOQuery do
      begin
        Connection:= ADOConnection1;
        SQL.Text:= 'SELECT ... WHERE Table.nuentrada = :Param';
        Parameters.ParamByName('Param').Value:= Num;
        Open;
        DataSource.DataSet:= ADOQuery;
      end;
  finally
    //ADOQuery.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

<sub>[1] [documentos on-line](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).</sub>

<sub>[2] [Injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).</sub>